# How to use actor-critique method in reinforcement learning to calculate slope when there are multiple behavioral probabilities, and more questions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to run reinforcement learning with actor-critic methods

Link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/rl/actor_critic_cartpole.py

The agent takes as input a map of size max_x * max_y, randomly filled with 1s or 0s.

The agent then updates the map by returning each step's x, y, and z probabilities.

Each step is trained to change the map to equal target_map, which is initialized at the beginning of training and is rewarded +1 for changing the map with that action and getting closer to target_map, 0 for failing to change the map, and -1 for changing the map incorrectly.

The episode ends when target_map and cur_map become the same or when it receives a -1 reward.

where x and y are positions on the map and z is 0 or 1.

So I have a few questions.

1. Did I train with the regular rewards?
2. To calculate the loss, I am using the probabilities of X, Y, and Z like the code below, is there a problem?

```
while True
   episode_reward = 0
   state = env.reset()

   for in step_per_episode
   
      x_probs, y_probs, z_probs, critic_value = model(state)
      critic_value_history.append(critic_value[0, 0])

      x = np.random.choice(np.arange(max_x), p=np.squeeze(x_probs[:max_x]))
      y = np.random.choice(np.arange(max_y), p=np.squeeze(y_probs[:max_y]))
      z = np.random.choice(np.arange(2), p=np.squeeze(tile_probs[:2]))
      
      #this
      action_probs_history.append(tf.math.log(x_probs[x] * y_probs[y] * z_probs[z]))

      state, reward, done = env.step(x, y, z)
      rewards_history.append(reward)
      episode_reward += reward

   running_reward = running_reward * (1 - episode_weight) + episode_reward * episode_weight
            
   # Calculate expected value from rewards
   returns = []
   discounted_sum = 0           
   for r in rewards_history[::-1]:
      discounted_sum = r + gamma * discounted_sum
      returns.insert(0, discounted_sum)
   
   # Normalize
   returns = np.array(returns)
   returns = (returns - np.mean(returns)) / (np.std(returns) + eps)
   returns = returns.tolist()

   # Calculating loss values to update our network
   history = zip(action_probs_history, critic_value_history, returns)
   actor_losses = []
   critic_losses = []

   for log_prob, value, ret in history:
      diff = ret - value
      actor_losses.append(-log_prob * diff)  

      critic_losses.append(huber_loss(tf.expand_dims(value, 0), tf.expand_dims(ret, 0)))
            
   # Backpropagation
   loss_value = sum(actor_losses) + sum(critic_losses)
   grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
   optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    
   action_probs_history.clear()
   critic_value_history.clear()
   rewards_history.clear()

.
.
.
```

I need help. welcome to comments. thanks.